# How to check for a list of wallets that interacted with a specific program id

Tags: anchor-program-idl

As the title says
Let's say I have a program id and I want to see a list of wallets that interacted with and filter by the type of interaction, how do I do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getSignaturesForAddress` for getting all signatures of the ProgramID (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress) and then you can use `getTransaction` on each signatures for get the details of each transactions (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction), and get wallets or others data you can need